# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create Adapter Class that extend `RecyclerView.Adapter`, so I need to add RecyclerView to gradle.

After I go to Dependencies and I search **EecyclerView** it shows me `"com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1"`
instead of `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"`

what should I do, now?

and after I add `"com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1"`, android studio message Gradle build shows me:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have mix version of Support Library. You need to use the same Support library version. If there is appCompat library in your module `build.gradle`, change it to the same version with RecyclerView. So, it should be like this:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   // NEVER USE alpha version in your production code.
   compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
}
```

If you can't found the conflicted support library in your dependencies, it means you have dependencies which using Support Library **implicitly**. Check it from dependencies tree with the following command in your terminal in **Linux**:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

or if you're using **Windows** try this in command prompt:

```
gradlew.bat app:dependencies
```

Then, after you found the conflicted Support Library, you need exclude it with:

```
compile('com.library.name:version') {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
  //exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Comment: In my case the error was because an alpha library: `implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-alpha02`